# Retorno Valor ID C# NpgsqlCommand

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

Após inserir uma linha de informação em determinada tabela, preciso recuperar o valor do ID para preencher meu objeto, meu código está assim:

```
using (NpgsqlConnection pgsqlConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(conn)
        {           
            pgsqlConnection.Open();
            String sql = "INSERT INTO public.localpo(NOME) VALUES (:nome)";
            using (NpgsqlCommand pgsqlcommand = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, pgsqlConnection))
            {
    pgsqlcommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("nome", "Ricardo Soares"));
            pgsqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Com esse código eu consigo inserir no banco de dados a informação sem problemas, ficando a dúvida, e para recuperar o id que foi gerado?

abaixo o codigo sql usado para gerar a tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE public.localpo (
id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('localpo_id_seq'::regclass),
nome character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
CONSTRAINT pk_id_localpo PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe um comando chamado returning que serve para justamente sua query retornar um dos campos, exemplo baseado na sua string:

```
INSERT INTO public.localpo(NOME) VALUES ('exemplo') returning id;
```

Comment: era isso mesmo que estava faltando

Answer (score 1):

Isso?

```
using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(conn) {           
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO public.localpo(NOME) VALUES (:nome)", conn)) {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("nome", "Ricardo Soares"));
        var IdInserido = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/GetId.cs).

Comment: acrescentei o seguindo codigo: var IdInserido = (int)pgsqlcommand.ExecuteScalar();
                        MessageBox.Show(IdInserido.ToString()); e retornou o erro: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Comment: Aí é outro erro, tem que ver o que fez errado, você deu um código, eu mostrei como resolver a questão com esse trecho, outros problemas eu não sei.

Comment: O código é exatamente o que te mandei, e esse é o erro que está dando