# Inserção de dados em duas tabelas em um único formulário

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Olá, bom dia!
Estou estudando WebForm na faculdade, e estou com uma dúvida para inserir um valor de um única pagina de formulário para duas Tabelas. No caso para exemplificar, tenho duas tabelas "Pessoa" e "Cliente". 
A tabela pes_pessoa tem os campos (pes_id, pes_nome) e cli_cliente (cli_id, pes_id, pes_observação). Porém não sei como inserir estes dados, pois necessito pela lógica inserir a pessoa para ter o id (por ser uma FK) para conseguir inserir um cliente. Seria dois INSERTS simultâneo na classe da Persistência? Eu sei, pela pesquisa de internet utilizar o ExecuteScalar() para pegar o último registro inserido da pessoa, mas não sei como cadastrar o cliente com estes dados.
Meu código está assim na classe PessoaDB p/ inserir.

```
public static int Inserir(Pessoa pes)
{
    int retorno = 0;
    try
    {
        IDbConnection objConexao;
        IDbCommand objComando;
        objConexao = Mapped.Connection();
        string sql = "INSERT INTO pes_pessoa(pes_nome) VALUES (?pes_nome) ; SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); ";
        objComando = Mapped.Command(sql, objConexao);
        objComando.Parameters.Add(Mapped.Parameter("?pes_id", pes.Id));
        objComando.Parameters.Add(Mapped.Parameter("?pes_nome", pes.Nome));
        retorno = Convert.ToInt32(objComando.ExecuteScalar());

        objConexao.Close();
        objComando.Dispose();
        objConexao.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        retorno = -2;
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

Classe ClienteDB

```
public static int Inserir(Cliente cli)
{
    int retorno = 0;
    try
    {
        IDbConnection objConexao;
        IDbCommand objComando;
        objConexao = Mapped.Connection();
        string sql = "INSERT INTO cli_cliente( cli_observacao, pes_id) VALUES ( ?cli_observacao, ?pes_id) ; SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); ";
        objComando = Mapped.Command(sql, objConexao);
        objComando.Parameters.Add(Mapped.Parameter("?cli_id", cli.Id));
        objComando.Parameters.Add(Mapped.Parameter("?cli_observacao", cli.Observacao));
        objComando.Parameters.Add(Mapped.Parameter("?pes_id", cli.Pessoa));
        retorno = Convert.ToInt32(objComando.ExecuteScalar());
        objConexao.Close();
        objComando.Dispose();
        objConexao.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        retorno = -2;
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

Comment: Lamento que esteja aprendendo uma tecnologia abandonada há quase 15 anos (na verdade lamento que estejam ensinando tecnologias específicas), e espero que a faculdade não tenha indicado fazer o código assim, embora ele não tenha alguns problema típicos, tem outros como a chamada de `Dispose()` ou `Close()` em vez de usar o padrão de `using`, inclusive com a criação de uma classe que tem um padrão que dependa de disposição sem sua correta implementação, capturar `Excepion`, usar código de erro indiscriminadamente, e os nomes das colunas do DB são bem tuins porque usam notação húngara.

Comment: Não posso afirmar 100%, mas parabéns por tratar `Cliente` como um papel de `Pessoa` e não como se fosse uma `Pessoa` como todo mundo erra. Só cuidado com aprendizado baseado em pesquisa na internet. As vezes você acha nela gente dizendo que a Terra é plana. Eu sei, você deve rir nessa hora porque sabe que isso é mentira. Mas em um assunto que não domina se o primeiro que ver for um mentira ou coisa errada desse tamanho você aprenderá errado.

Comment: Claro que tem muita coisa certa também, mas você ainda não é capaz de avaliar isto quando está aprendendo. Pelos padrões que todo mundo faz é isso mesmo, você insere um pega o código obtido e o outro recebe esse `id` obtido antes para uso no que precisa. Não vi um problema claro na sua pergunta. Tem como fazer isso de outra forma e pode ser uma forma atômica, garantindo que ambos sejam inseridos ao mesmo tempo com garantia.

Comment: Nem sempre isso é necessário neste caso porque a `Pessoa` deveria poder existir sem o papel de `Cliente` existir, e a adição de `Cliente` deveria poder ocorrer quando a `Pessoa` já existe, portanto deveria ter uma lógica para tratar essa possibilidade. Se eu tivesse entendido a dúvida talvez eu desse uma resposta, ainda dá pra melhorar nisso. Veja que está escrevendo código desnecessário: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/328008/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/99820/101. Talvez isto tenha respondido sua questão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44648/101.

Comment: Sobre o assunto que falei de problemas, tem mais informações aqui no site para entender melhor e o conteúdo foi classificado por diversas pessoas, então a chance dele estar certo é grande, pesquise e analise.